# How to hide Query string parameter in ReactJS react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

On click of Link am passing query string parameter and am reading it on another page then am doing my logic. but I want to hide the query string from URL. this is how am passing parameters

```
<Link  to={{ pathname: '/user', query: { id: this.props.id } }} > User List </Link>
```

Comment: this is how am passing params User List
<Link  to={{ pathname: '/details', query: { id: this.props.id } }}  > More Details... </Link>

Comment: Basically you cannot hide the query strings from the url.You can store somewhere to use it but url the only option where you can pass query parameters to receive in another page.

Comment: for example if i  the query string will appear  like this at URL http://xxxxx ?id=1001 then some one can hit 1002 can check  details of 1002 's   also right . how to protect

Comment: Then do one thing.Mix the id with some random characters which u know how to mix and that cannot be easily extracted.So it is like adding a hash in password.You can do that if you want that much security.Otherwise different tabs cannot show different content if you save that id some where else.

Comment: If the goal is to keep the query parameters private then how is adding random characters on the front end going to achieve that when anyone can see what these random characters are?

Comment: nice great idea   i will try thank you so much

Comment: hi @therewillbecode so can't we achieve this by method of what satyaDash suggest.?

Comment: You can use his method but it won't be secure as anyone can use the browser to inspect code. It should be fine if you do the obfuscation server side as users are far less likely to have access to that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Programmatically navigate in react-router whilst hiding query string parameters**

Note the second argument takes an object of parameters. Use the following inside your component:

```
this.context.transitionTo("route", { search: this.state.search, type: this.state.type });
```

We need to use the class based component syntax to have access to the *this* keyword.For example:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class CustomLink extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.context.router.transitionTo("route", { search: this.state.search, type: this.state.type });
  }

  render(){
    return (<div onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</div>);
  }
}

customLink.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Comment: i imported already  browser history package like this .
import { Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

Comment: Should i give inside <Link to= ""> </Link> or  render function  of class/component

Comment: Again, see updated answer. Link is a react-router component and therefore wont have this custom functionality.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transitionTo' of undefined

Comment: Ensure that the name of the component is accurate when setting contextTypes. i.e if your component is called customLink then use customLink.contextTypes = ...